# Restructure json, where value doesnt exist set value to 0

Tags: javascript, json, object

Im trying to restructure data from a mysql query, ive spent days trying to figure out how to exactly do this.
mysql data:

```
var data = [{rep:'Test1', day: 1 , binder: 500},
{rep:'Test1', day: 2 , binder: 500},{rep:'Test1', day: 3 , binder: 500},
{rep:'Test2', day: 2 , binder: 500},{rep:'Test2', day: 2 , binder: 500},
{rep:'Test1', day: 4 , binder: 500},{rep:'Test1', day: 5 , binder: 500},
{rep:'Test2', day: 4 , binder: 500},{rep:'Test1', day: 5 , binder: 500},
{rep:'Test1', day: 6 , binder: 500},{rep:'Test2', day: 7 , binder: 500}]
```

into a readable object for datatables

```
    var data = { 
"data": [
    [
      "Test1",
      "500", // total Binder from monday for Test1
      "500", // total Binder from Tuesday for Test1
      "500", // total Binder from wednesday for Test1
      "500", // total Binder from thursday for Test1
      "1000", // total Binder from friday for Test1
      "500" // total Binder from saturday for Test1
      "500", // total Binder from sunday for Test1
      "4000" // sum of all previous 
    ],[
      "Test2",
      "500", // total Binder from monday for Test2
      "500", // total Binder from Tuesday for Test2
      "500", // total Binder from wednesday for Test2
      "500", // total Binder from thursday for Test2
      "1000", // total Binder from friday for Test2
      "500" // total Binder from saturday for Test2
      "500", // total Binder from sunday for Test2
      "4000" // sum of all previous 
    ]
    
  ]
}
```

the current function i have is

```
const transformObj = (repKey) => { 
const days = [ 
"Sunday", 
"Monday", 
"Tuesday", 
"Wednesday", 
"Thursday", 
"Friday", 
"Saturday" 
]; 

let obj = {}; 

const filteredDatasets = data.filter( 
(d) => d.rep.toLowerCase() === repKey.toLowerCase() 
); 

const total = filteredDatasets.reduce( 
(prevValue, currDataset) => prevValue + currDataset.binder, 
0 
); 

filteredDatasets.forEach((dataset) => { 
obj = { ...obj, rep: dataset.rep, [days[dataset.day - 1]]: dataset.binder }; 
}); 

obj.total = total; 

return obj; 
};
```

which returns

```
{ rep: "Test1", Monday: (some int), Tuesday:(some int), total: 1500 }
```

with the current function, if a specific day day isnt in the Source data, it wont be included in the output
im not sure how to accomplish this, and i am trying to teach myself js

Comment: Why in your desired output you have 500 for Monday (for test1 and test2). I don't see this in our input. Same for several other numbers... Why is "Jeff" not in your output? The total of all binder numbers in the input is 5500, ... how come your output has two totals of 4000? Why is your code working with day names? What is deals? I really don't see any logic here.

Comment: @trincot my mistake, i did my best to type out the source data and output by hand.. but i should have fixed most of the errors... any error in values not adding up is not a feature just a mistake on myend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There seems little consistency between the input data, the desired output and your code. If I just rely on the input data, and the *shape* of the desired output, I would propose a process where you first create a Map keyed by the `rep` values, associating the desired array structure with it.

Then populate those arrays by iterating over the data.

Finally extract those arrays to build the final data structure:

```js
let data = [{rep:'Test1', day: 1 , binder: 500},{rep:'Test1', day: 2 , binder: 500},{rep:'Test1', day: 3 , binder: 500},{rep:'Test2', day: 2 , binder: 500},{rep:'Test2', day: 2 , binder: 500},{rep:'Test1', day: 4 , binder: 500},{rep:'Test1', day: 5 , binder: 500},{rep:'Test2', day: 4 , binder: 500},{rep:'Test1', day: 5 , binder: 500},{rep:'Test1', day: 6 , binder: 500},{rep:'Test2', day: 7 , binder: 500}];

let reps = new Map(data.map(({rep}) => [rep, [rep, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0]]));
for (let {rep, day, binder} of data) {
    let arr = reps.get(rep);
    arr[8] += arr[day] = binder;
}
let result = { data: [...reps.values()] };

console.log(result);
```